# Model Class with ObjectMapper Error Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Tags: ios, alamofire, xcode9, swift4, objectmapper

I'm getting error : Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties  on init()

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

struct ProductGroup: Mappable {

var group_title: String
var group_type :String
var products: Array<Products>


  init?(map: Map) {


}



 mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.group_title     <- map["group_title"]
    self.group_type <- map["group_type"]
    self.products   <- map["products"]
}
}
```

Comment: try to make all properties optional OR initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***try to make all properties optional OR initialize it***

**Refer Document** : https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

**i also attached one screenshort from Document that will let you solved your problem :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are **var** & **not optional** then you must need to **initialise** it and if you don't want to do like that then you must need to apply **var** as a **optional.**

Like below

```
var group_title: String?
var group_type :String?
var products: Array<Products>?
```